# How do I resize this table for a beamer presentation?

Tags: tables, beamer, resize

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{netinmargin}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{netinmargin}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{netinmargin}\\
\hline
infltn      &  -0.0000703* &   -0.000157  &      0.0230* \\
            &     (-2.16)  &     (-1.72)  &      (2.12)  \\
[1em]
fdi         &     -0.0405**&     -0.0364* &     -0.0189  \\
            &     (-3.80)  &     (-2.54)  &     (-0.21)  \\
[1em]
GDP         &     -0.0260  &     -0.0300  &     -0.0525* \\
            &     (-0.58)  &     (-0.75)  &     (-2.58)  \\
[1em]
roa         &              &       0.921**&      0.0126  \\
            &              &      (4.55)  &      (0.07)  \\
[1em]
roe         &              &     -0.0107  &      0.0877**\\
            &              &     (-0.44)  &      (7.11)  \\
[1em]
bcbd        &              &     0.00472  &     -0.0112  \\
            &              &      (0.56)  &     (-0.91)  \\
[1em]
dbacba      &              &     -0.0620**&     -0.0827**\\
            &              &     (-2.75)  &     (-3.70)  \\
[1em]
cbagdp      &              &    -0.00347  &      -0.106**\\
            &              &     (-0.11)  &     (-3.65)  \\
[1em]
llgdp       &              &      -0.212**&      -0.168* \\
            &              &     (-4.12)  &     (-2.28)  \\
[1em]
dbagdp      &              &      0.0532  &      0.0841* \\
            &              &      (1.78)  &      (2.05)  \\
[1em]
fdgdp       &              &       0.135**&       0.124* \\
            &              &      (2.73)  &      (2.43)  \\
[1em]
ll\_usd      &              &              &  0.00000381  \\
            &              &              &      (0.62)  \\
[1em]
overhead    &              &              &       0.699**\\
            &              &              &      (7.30)  \\
[1em]
xregme      &              &              &      -0.931  \\
            &              &              &     (-1.95)  \\
[1em]
nrbloan     &              &              &      0.0228  \\
            &              &              &      (0.48)  \\
[1em]
stmktcap    &              &              &     -0.0440* \\
            &              &              &     (-2.55)  \\
[1em]
stvaltraded &              &              &       0.255* \\
            &              &              &      (2.44)  \\
[1em]
stturnover  &              &              &     -0.0123  \\
            &              &              &     (-1.32)  \\
[1em]
listco\_pc   &              &              &   -0.000506  \\
            &              &              &     (-1.86)  \\
[1em]
\_cons      &       7.404**&       11.72**&       10.18**\\
            &     (34.15)  &      (4.67)  &      (4.14)  \\
\hline
\(N\)       &         470  &         452  &         102  \\
\(R^{2}\)   &       0.017  &       0.363  &       0.887  \\
adj. \(R^{2}\)&       0.011  &       0.347  &       0.860  \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize "test line 1" "test line 2"}\\
\end{tabular}}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Unless you want to make your audience either laugh out loud or turn away in despair, do *not* show such a long table in a `beamer` presentation. After all, what is the audience supposed to remember from this table and from your talk in general? Hopefully not, "yeah, the presentation with the ridiculously long table".

Comment: Please don't use `\resizebox` for tables

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

even if you reorganize table, as is done in example below, you will have problem to fit it in one frame ... only with reduce font size to `\scriptsize` and reduce stretching of lines is possible to obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=-2.8,
                       table-align-text-post=false]@{\,}r
                 S[table-format=-2.6,
                       table-align-text-post=false]@{\,}r
                 S[table-format=-2.8,
                       table-align-text-post=false]@{\,}r
                @{}}
    \toprule
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)}
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}       \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
        & {netinmargin}
                      &  ???     & {netinmargin}
                                            &  ???    & {netinmargin}
                                                                &  ???      \\
    \midrule
infltn  & -0.0000703* & (-2.16) & -0.000157 & (-1.72) &  0.0230* & ( 2.12)  \\
fdi     & -0.0405**   & (-3.80) & -0.0364*  & (-2.54) & -0.0189  & (-0.21)  \\
GDP     & -0.0260     & (-0.58) & -0.0300   & (-0.75) & -0.0525* & (-2.58)  \\
roa     &             &         &  0.921**  & (4.55)  &  0.0126  & (0.07)   \\
roe     &             &         & -0.0107   & (-0.44) &  0.0877**& (7.11)   \\[2pt]

bcbd    &             &         &  0.00472  & (0.56)  & -0.0112  & (-0.91)  \\
dbacba  &             &         & -0.0620** & (-2.75) & -0.0827**& (-3.70)  \\
cbagdp  &             &         & -0.00347  & (-0.11) & -0.106** & (-3.65)  \\
llgdp   &             &         & -0.212**  & (-4.12) & -0.168*  & (-2.28)  \\
dbagdp  &             &         &  0.0532   & (1.78)  &  0.0841* & (2.05)   \\[2pt]

fdgdp   &             &         &  0.135**  & (2.73)  &  0.124*  & (2.43)   \\
ll\_usd &             &         &           &         &  0.00000381 & (0.62)\\
overhead&             &         &           &         &  0.699** & (7.30)   \\
xregme  &             &         &           &         & -0.931   & (-1.95)  \\
nrbloan &             &         &           &         &  0.0228  & (0.48)   \\[2pt]

stmktcap    &         &         &           &         & -0.0440* & (-2.55)  \\
stvaltraded &         &         &           &         &  0.255*  & (2.44)   \\
stturnover  &         &         &           &         & -0.0123  & (-1.32)  \\
listco\_pc  &         &         &           &         & -0.000506& (-1.86)  \\
\_cons      & 7.404** & (34.15) & 11.72**   & (4.67)  & 10.18**  & (4.14)   \\[2pt]

\(N\)       & 470     &         & 452       &         & 102      &          \\
\(R^{2}\)   & 0.017   &         & 0.363     &         &  0.887   &          \\
adj. \(R^{2}\)  & 0.011     &   & 0.347     &         &  0.860   &          \\
    \midrule[1pt]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize "test line 1" "test line 2"} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table has a two-row header, 20 double rows (coefficient estimates and either standard errors or t-stats, right?), plus some rows with supplemental information. The only way one can get all 45 rows to fit in a single frame is to reduce the table so drastically as to make it virtually unreadable.

If you really, absolutely, positively must show all 20 double rows -- you're going to comment each and every row for the benefit of your audience, right? -- the only constructive suggestion I can make is to break up the large table into four subtables, each with a header and a frame title. Something like the following, then:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Long table, part 1 of 4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ld{3.8}*{2}{d{3.6}}}
\toprule
&\mc{(1)}&\mc{(2)}&\mc{(3)}\\
&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}\\
\midrule
infltn      & -0.0000703^{*} &   -0.000157  & 0.0230^{*} \\
            &   (-2.16)      &     (-1.72)  &  (2.12)    \\[1ex]
fdi         &    -0.0405^{**}&  -0.0364^{*} &   -0.0189  \\
            &     (-3.80)  &     (-2.54)  &     (-0.21)  \\[1ex]
GDP         &     -0.0260  &     -0.0300  &  -0.0525^{*} \\
            &     (-0.58)  &     (-0.75)  &     (-2.58)  \\[1ex]
roa         &              &    0.921^{**}&      0.0126  \\
            &              &      (4.55)  &      (0.07)  \\[1ex]
roe         &              &     -0.0107  &   0.0877^{**}\\
            &              &     (-0.44)  &      (7.11)  \\[1ex]
bcbd        &              &     0.00472  &     -0.0112  \\
            &              &      (0.56)  &     (-0.91)  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Long table, part 2 of 4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{d{3.8}}}
\toprule
&\mc{(1)}&\mc{(2)}&\mc{(3)}\\
&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}\\
\midrule
dbacba      &              &  -0.0620^{**}&  -0.0827^{**}\\
            &              &    (-2.75)   &     (-3.70)  \\[1ex]
cbagdp      &              &    -0.00347  &   -0.106^{**}\\
            &              &     (-0.11)  &    (-3.65)   \\[1ex]
llgdp       &              &   -0.212^{**}&   -0.168^{*} \\
            &              &     (-4.12)  &    (-2.28)   \\[1ex]
dbagdp      &              &      0.0532  &   0.0841^{*} \\
            &              &      (1.78)  &      (2.05)  \\[1ex]
fdgdp       &              &    0.135^{**}&    0.124^{*} \\
            &              &      (2.73)  &      (2.43)  \\[1ex]
ll\_usd     &              &              &  0.00000381  \\
            &              &              &      (0.62)  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Long table, part 3 of 4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{d{3.8}}}
\toprule
&\mc{(1)}&\mc{(2)}&\mc{(3)}\\
&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}\\
\midrule
overhead    &              &              &       0.699^{**}\\
            &              &              &      (7.30)  \\[1ex]
xregme      &              &              &      -0.931  \\
            &              &              &     (-1.95)  \\[1ex]
nrbloan     &              &              &      0.0228  \\
            &              &              &      (0.48)  \\[1ex]
stmktcap    &              &              &     -0.0440^{*} \\
            &              &              &     (-2.55)  \\[1ex]
stvaltraded &              &              &       0.255^{*} \\
            &              &              &      (2.44)  \\[1ex]
stturnover  &              &              &     -0.0123  \\
            &              &              &     (-1.32)  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Long table, part 4 of 4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ld{3.5}d{2.4}d{3.6}}
\toprule
&\mc{(1)}&\mc{(2)}&\mc{(3)}\\
&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}&\mc{netinmargin}\\
\midrule
listco\_pc  &              &              &   -0.000506    \\
            &              &              &     (-1.86)    \\[1ex]
\_const     &   7.404^{**} &   11.72^{**} &      10.18^{**}\\
            &     (34.15)  &      (4.67)  &      (4.14)    \\
\midrule
\(N\)       &     \mc{470} &     \mc{452} &     \mc{102} \\
\(R^{2}\)   &       0.017  &       0.363  &       0.887  \\
adj.\ \(R^{2}\)&    0.011  &       0.347  &       0.860  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```